# SSRS Report Manager - Subscription not being started by Agent Job

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

We currently have an issue where the report subscription is not being started by the linked SQL Agent Job.  The SQL Agent job runs on the correct schedule, completes successfully but the report subscription itself does not start.  This is happening across a few of our subscriptions, all of which are data driven.

Checking the SQL logs there's no errors, there are no errors in the event viewer and there's no errors in the report manager logs, in fact, when one report was supposed to run at 6:19 there was no entry in the report manager logs at all, but when I re-ran the subscription later it ran fine and then put an entry in to the report manager logs.  (Re-running the subscription doesn't always work first time)

From everything we have looked at the issue appears to be that the Agent Jobs triggers the request for the subscription to run but the subscription does not start, I'm not sure if the request is even making it to the report server, but given there is no failure logs on the report server I'm leaning towards the request not making it.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

For reference this is on SQL Server 2016 with SSRS 2016.

TIA,

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

It looks like upgrading to "SQL Server 2016 CU13" is going to solve the problem, still testing but initial signs looks good.

The working assumption is that the windows updates that installed recently required a newer version of SQL.